# Django/Apache error "attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: python, django, apache

I am lost, i have tried everything about this issue and can't find solution.
I have the app on django 1.8 / python 3.3.5 / centos 7 / apache. It is default sqlite db here. Everytihng is working fine with django's webserver but fails with error "attempt to write a readonly database" on Apache.
I have done all checks according to this doc https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3
db file and it's root folder have write permissions and "apache apache" user owner but it is still the same error:

```
OperationalError at /logout/
attempt to write a readonly database
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://app.server.corp/logout/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
attempt to write a readonly database
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-            packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3.3/
```

Comment: Could it be an issue with SELinux security context? I had similar issues in the past.

Comment: You was totaly right! it was problem in SELinux, after turning off app starts work correctly

Comment: I added an answer with the comment.

Comment: http://stopdisablingselinux.com

Answer (score 8):

Its because there was “attempt to write a readonly database”
so for me helped following in shell:

```
chmod 755 db.sqlite3
```

So we are just changing a permissions to DB file. In other words Server cannot write to file.

Comment: Dmitry, thank you for your answer! There were issue with enabled SELinux. As i have read before it is not so secure to use chmod 777, better way to use 755 permissions with apache user as owner of this file.

Comment: If my answer was effective, please plus it :)